# How to Dock ArcMap's Table of Contents?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I have ArcView 10.1 and am, without luck, searching for/how to "dock the TOC" on the left hand side of the screen.

When I grab the TOC, I see the buttons light up with arrows for up/down, left/right etc.

How do I dock the TOC?

Comment: Sree, you are a life saver!!! I got so fed up with that blue rectangle thing!!! It never ever worked for me. Felt like an idiot. Just simple do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After your grab the TOC, you should see a translucent blue rectangle that represents the new location of the TOC. Drag your cursor over to the left arrow/chevron (either one). The translucent rectangle will change size to show its docked position. Release, and the window should be docked.

Comment: HAHA, I tried that earlier. It's been one of those days.   Thank You, Kennedy.

Answer (score 12):

When you have grabbed the TOC and see the buttons, drag the TOC until your Mouse is hovering over the Left Button.  You will see the shadow appear of the TOC docked on the left side.  Then release and the TOC will dock.
[image: Docking of TOC]

Comment: Thanks, Get Spatial! I couldn't figure out how to capture the screen properly.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to dock is double clicking TOC.